# Using java in rascal

Tags: rascal

I have made a java function genImage(List<String lines) which is located in class vis. I am trying to import it into my rascal code, but it won't work. This is the last of my efforts to import it:

```
@javaClass{visualization.vis} 
java void genImage(list[str] lines);
```

The error I get:

> Cannot link method visualization.vis because: visualization.vis.(io.usethesource.vallang.IValueFactory)
> Advice: |http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Errors/Static/JavaMethodLink/JavaMethodLink.html%7C

Comment: Don't post images of text

Comment: I should have realized that! Thank you, I have edited it.

Comment: As an addition to Marcin Orlowski's comment, you should consider quoting code and tools output with backticks \`. For instance, \`code\` is displayed like this: `code`. It usually makes the question easier to read as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

The `@javaClass` tag must point to a fully qualified classname, including the package and the class. It seems it's the class you are missing, right?